# Why is my Python script to find text on multiple webpages, running from terminal taking so long to run?

Tags: python, macos, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, terminal

I am using the following Python to search multiple webpages for certain text then print the text it finds and any HREFs associated with the text. However, the script seems to be taking forever to run from terminal (over an hour with no results to scan 3 websites). Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#Sites to scan
url_list = ["somesite1","somesite2","somesite3"]

#Keywords to search
the_word = 'Some Text'

total_words = []
for url in url_list:
    r = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=False)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content.lower(), 'lxml')
    words = soup.find_all(text=lambda text: text and the_word.lower() in text)
    count = len(words)
    words_list = [ ele.strip() for ele in words ]
    for word in words:
        total_words.append(word.strip())

print('\nUrl: {}\ncontains {} of word: {}'.format(url, count, the_word))
print(words_list)


#print(total_words)
total_count = len(total_words)
```

Comment: Can you share the URL of the site and text you want to find?

Comment: I have a list of sites, and am doing a case study for school. Trying to see which sites have a "Do Not Sell My Personal Information" link and which don't. Example sites: apple.com, cnn.com etc.